# Filtering the key value pair in hadoop reducer function in R

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to know how can I put conditions to filter out key, value pair in hadoop reducer function. For example, in the word count example given below, how can I get on those words whose count is greater than some threshold value say, 3.

```
library(rmr2)
library(rhdfs)

# initiate rhdfs package
hdfs.init()

map <- function(k,lines) {
  words.list <- strsplit(lines, '\\s')
  words <- unlist(words.list)
  return( keyval(words, 1) )
}

reduce <- function(word, counts) {
  keyval(word, sum(counts))
}

wordcount <- function (input, output=NULL) {
  mapreduce(input=input, output=output, input.format="text", map=map, reduce=reduce)
}

## read text files from folder example/wordcount/data
hdfs.root <- 'example/wordcount'
hdfs.data <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'data')

## save result in folder example/wordcount/out
hdfs.out <- file.path(hdfs.root, 'out')

## Submit job
out <- wordcount(hdfs.data, hdfs.out) 

## Fetch results from HDFS
results <- from.dfs(out)
results.df <- as.data.frame(results, stringsAsFactors=F)
colnames(results.df) <- c('word', 'count')

head(results.df)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an if statement to your reduce function? An if statement can go long ways

Comment: I don't really understand how can I put the if condition in the reduce function. I did think of the same and tried something like this

cnt <- sum(counts)
if(cnt > threshold){
    keyval(word, counts)
}

but I have a doubt that how will it sum only those counts whose word is same.

Comment: It's my turn not to understand. There's only one word in the reducer. Only one count. The sameness is solved in the shuffle.

Comment: I mean if I do the sum(counts), will it not do the sum over all the counts irrespective of what the word was. How does the word, and its corresponding frequency maintained?

Comment: That's a separate problem. Since wordcount works, sum(counts) by some miracle does the right thing. So by the same miracle, you can write `if(sum(counts) > 44)`. You have to convince yourself wordcount works before you can modify it.

Comment: Yeah, it works. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reduce <- function(word, counts) {
  if(sum(counts) > 3)
    keyval(word, sum(counts))
}
```